# How can I add a new column with forecasts?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to Forecast with the ARIMA-Model . My question is, how to create a new Column that contains my forecasted values with the new Date in the Future (based on the steps in the Future)..this is my Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv("Desktop/Daten/probe.csv",sep=";")
df["Monthes"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Monthes"], infer_datetime_format=True)
indexedDf = df.set_index(["Monthes"])
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(indexedDf, order =(1,1,2))
results_ARIMA = model.fit(disp=0)
n = 120 # 1 year Forecasting
result = results_ARIMA.forecast(steps=n)[0]
```

How can i put the result of Forecasting in new Tab with the new 'n' Monthes ? ..

Comment: Can you show the dataframe? Do you have the dates for your predictions? You can create a range of dates using `pd.date_range()`, concat the prediction and the new dates you generated, and then append to your original dataframe.

Comment: the data frame looks like this :  
Monthes                           Sales
2017-01-01 01:15:00 4.615121
2017-02-01 02:30:00      4.499810
2017-03-01 15:30:00 3.583519
2017-04-01  01:15:00 4.553877
.....                 ......             ........                                                                                            i've got results of Predections based on the number of the steps and i want to append the predictions to the suitable dates.. Thanks for replying

Comment: it works with this sentence: t = pd.date_range(start=(df.Monthes[len(dataset)-1]) , periods=n) but how to append t and the results together? thanks

Comment: Combine them using pd.concat(), and make sure the length of both is same.

Comment: @pissall it worked thanks a lot!! how can i combine them in two different columns? so that i have the new Dates in a column and the predictions in the next column

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

Suppose your dataframe looks like this:

```
         date  spend
0  2019-11-10    800
1  2019-11-11    800
2  2019-11-12    300
3  2019-11-13    150
4  2019-11-14    300
5  2019-11-15    500
6  2019-11-16    800
7  2019-11-17    600
8  2019-11-18    400
```

```
n = 5
t = pd.date_range(start=(df.date[len(df)-1]) , periods=n)
# assume predictions
predictions = np.random.rand(5) * 1000
# array([619.34810384, 600.78387725, 242.4680893 , 920.58391429, 489.36016082])
new_df = pd.DataFrame([[x, y] for x,y in zip(t, predictions)], columns=["date", "spend"])
print(new_df)
        date      spend
0 2019-11-19  94.944353
1 2019-11-20  64.813264
2 2019-11-21  56.319640
3 2019-11-22  81.696114
4 2019-11-23  43.533978
```

Now finally you can just concat/append it to your dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df, new_df]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**output**

```
         date  spend
0  2019-11-10    800
1  2019-11-11    800
2  2019-11-12    300
3  2019-11-13    150
4  2019-11-14    300
5  2019-11-15    500
6  2019-11-16    800
7  2019-11-17    600
8  2019-11-18    400
9  2019-11-19    94.944353
10 2019-11-20    64.813264
11 2019-11-21    56.319640
12 2019-11-22    81.696114
13 2019-11-23    43.533978
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add this column to your dataframe (`df`), here's what you need to do.

```py
df['result`] = result
```

If you want to write this result to an excel spreadsheet with the sheet renamed as the date-of-result,

```py
N = [30, 60, 90, 120]
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    # if you want to write multiple forecasts to 
    # the same file, but in different spreadsheets
    for n in N: 
        result = results_ARIMA.forecast(steps=n)[0]
        df['result'] = result
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_n={}'.format(n))
```

If you want to name the sheet with tomorrow's date (2019-11-22), then just change `sheet_name='2019-11-22'`.

#### How to get tomorrow's date?

```py
import datetime
def tomorrow():
    return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(tomorrow())
```

#### Conversion of Date to String:

```py
dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I would encourage you to look at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for more clarity on `pandas.ExcelWriter`.

Comment: What do you mean by **"a new tab"**? Are you trying write this result to an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @CyperherX . yes i want to write the resulst but with the suitable Dates. For exemple i want to forecast for tomorrow so the result musst be with the date of tomorrow.. hope you understand my question and thank  you for replying

Comment: @AhmedMadiouni Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! i've created a new Dates using: t = pd.date_range(start=(df.Monthes[len(df)-1]) , periods=n). Do you know how to combine this Dates with result? to get an array with Dates and predictions?

Comment: @AhmedMadiouni Please update the question to reflect these details. I have included what you need to do to convert dates into strings. But, let's limit the question here. If you have anything else that you need to know to solve your overall requirement, please open a new question/search for a question if that already answers your query.

Comment: @AhmedMadiouni Please consider to **`vote up`** and **`accept`** the answer. Thank you.